# Using Parse.com query.equalTo() to match a number

Tags: jquery, regex, parse-platform

In the object stored in cloud, the field is `phone` which is a number

I can use `query.matches(key,regex,modifiers)` or `query.equalTo(key,value)` and match `name` or `objectID` which are stored as string.
I used both these methods for the number and they dont return anything.

Is there anyway to get an object by comparing a number?

Comment: M8 you need to provide us with your regex, samples etc etc

Comment: regex match is not working. If equalTo works, thats more than enough for me. But even that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found the answer,

If the data is stored as a number in the object, it must be compared with an integer itself. So while doing `query.equalTo()`, value must also be an integer or a number. Did a simple `parseInt()` to get the number and it works now.